# Single-pass algorithm for kurtosis

Tags: matlab, algorithms, skewness, online-algorithms, kurtosis

Here is a simple test I've run on MATLAB to check the validity of a single pass (online) algorithm for computing $3$rd moment and $4$th moment.

```
randn('state',0);

num2 = 0;
num1 = 0;
delta = 0;  
M1 = 0;
M2 = 0;
M3 = 0;
M4 = 0;

Xvec = zeros(1, 100000);

for j = 1:length(Xvec)

    X = 3*randn(1);

    % Single pass algorithm   
    num2  = num1;
    num1  = num1 + 1;
    delta = X - M1;
    delta_n  = delta / num1;
    delta_n2 = delta_n * delta_n;
    term1 = delta *delta_n * num2;
    M1 = M1 + delta_n;
    M4 = M4 + term1 * delta_n2 * (num1 * num1 - 3.0*num1 + 3.0) + ...
    6.0 * delta_n2 * M2 - 4.0 * delta_n * M3;
    M3 = M3 + term1 * delta_n * (num1 - 2.0) - 3.0 * delta_n * M2;
    M2 = M2 + term1;

    Xvec(j) = X;
end
% Quantities obtained from Single Pass
avg = M1;
variance = M2 / (num1 - 1.0);
kurtosis = (num1 * M4)/(M2 * M2) - 3.0;
skewness = sqrt(num1) * M3 / (M2^1.5);

% Reference Quantities 
avg1     = sum /length(Xvec);
moment_2 = moment(Xvec, 2);
moment_3 = moment(Xvec, 3);
moment_4 = moment(Xvec, 4);
```

The online algorithm provides a correct mean (avg = avg1) and variance (variance = moment_2). However, the values for kurtosis and skewness obtained from the online algorithm are way off from the actual $3$rd and $4$th moments.

What might be going wrong?

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance)

Comment: kurtosis and skewness are not the third and fourth moments. Please be explicit about what you're comparing with what and if at all possible, show what the functions you call calculate (such as `moment`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, you've changed the notation from the Wikipedia article in a way that is quite confusing. You've replaced $m$ with $M_1$ which is not consistent with $M_2$, $M_3$ and $M_4$. $M_k$ is defined as $\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^k$ whereas $m$ is the running mean.

In case this is where the source of the confusion lies: $M_k$ is not the $k$-th central moment. $\frac{M_k}{n}$ is.

Another possible source of confusion: from your question you seem to imply that the kurtosis and skewness should equal the third and fourth central moments which they do not - as you can see from the very calculations you are performing to calculate them:

```
kurtosis = (num1 * M4)/(M2 * M2) - 3.0;
skewness = sqrt(num1) * M3 / (M2^1.5);
```

I do not know exactly how the `moment()` function is implemented in Matlab but assuming it calculates central moments then you should see that your value for `kurtosis` is equal to `moment_4/moment_2^2 - 3.0`