# Good algorithm to compute the sample mean and variance

Tags: variance, mean, sample, numerics

I am looking for good (fast, memory efficient, ideally one-pass) algorithms to compute the sample mean and variance.

I have found a technical report by [Chan, Golub, and LeVeque](http://cpsc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/tr222.pdf) from 1983 with interesting algorithms. Are there more modern improvements?

EDIT: Added the crucial words "and variance"

Comment: My canonical reference would be the [*Numerical Recipes*](http://numerical.recipes/) (in C, or whatever). I wouldn't expect CV to be very useful for actual statistical algorithms. If you don't get good answers here, you may want to consider flagging your question and asking a moderator to migrate it to [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Algorithms of this sort--for many more statistics than the mean--can be found by [searching our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=online+mean+algorithm).  (There are hundreds of hits.  I'm not sure why @StephanKolassa thinks we are not a good site to ask such questions.)  The duplicate concerns a more difficult version of your question, but it is answered directly in one of the replies.

Comment: The  Chan, Golub, and LeVeque paper addresses numerical computation of sample variance, and is not really focused on sample mean. Which are you really interested in? You may consider http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ as a possible site for your (to be clarified) question.

Comment: In light of the edit, I have redirected this thread to a different duplicate (that addresses both the mean and the variance).  Also see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88837/single-pass-algorithm-for-kurtosis, as well as other hits in a site search for [online variance algorithm.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=online+variance+algorithm)

Comment: @whuber: Being "online" is not a requirement (in fact, I'd be happy not to deal with factors like (n-1)/n and 1/n until the final computation of the variance).

Comment: I'm curious about the distinction you are making.  If a "fast, memory-efficient, one-pass" algorithm isn't "online," then how does it differ?  The factors of course are irrelevant because computing them requires only $O(1)$ storage and $O(n)$ time.